# Complex Hilbert Space, Positive operator,poisson formula

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

This question was left as an exercise in my class of Functional Analysis. Course is online.

> Question:  H is a complex Hilbert space.  (1) For any operator $S\in L(H)$  verfying ||S||<1, we pose $P_S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} S^n + I +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{S*}^n$. Justify this definition.

(2) Using the notation in (1) , show that we can write $P_S = (1- S*)^{-1} (Id - S^* S) (I-S)^{-1} $ and deduce that $P_S$ is a positive operator.

(3)  Let $T \in  L(H)$ , verify that ||T||<1. Show that the application $\theta \to P e^{-i\theta T}$ is continuous from $\mathbb{R}$  into L(H) , then show that for any polynomial $f\in \mathbb{C} [X]$ we have $f(T) = \int_{0}^{2\pi} f( e^{i \theta}) P_{e^{-i \theta T}} \frac{ d \theta } {2 \pi}$ . This formula is called operator poission formula.

Attempt:  (a)  I am not able to understand what it is meant by justifying this definition.

and unfortunately I don't also have much to show as an attempt on (b) and (c).

Kindly help me with this.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to show that the series defining $P_S$ are convergent. You can show that they are absolutely convergent.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|S^n\|\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \|S\|^n<\infty \\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \|(S^*)^n\|\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \|S^*\|^n=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|S\|^n<\infty $$
Thus the series defining $P_S$ are absolutely convergent, hence convergent. Observe that
$$(I-S)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty S^n=I+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (S^*)^n,\qquad (I-S^*)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (S^*)^n=I+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (S^*)^n$$
Hence
$$P_S=(I-S)^{-1}+(I-S^*)^{-1}-I\\ =(I-S^*)^{-1}[I-S^*+I-S-(I-S^*)(I-S)](I-S)^{-1}\\
= (I-S^*)^{-1}(I-S^*S)(I-S)^{-1}$$
As $\|S^*S\|=\|S\|^2<1,$ the operator $I-S^*S$ is positive.
Thus $P_S$ is positive as it is of the form $P_S=U^*(I-S^*S)U$
(with $U=(I-S)^{-1}$).

Concerning $(3),$ the correct formula is
$$f(T)={1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_0^{2\pi} f(e^{i\theta})P_{e^{-i\theta}T}\,d\theta \quad (*)$$
Indeed, we have
$$P_{e^{-i\theta}T}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-in\theta}T^n +\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{in\theta}(T^*)^n$$ and both series are absolutely convergent. By linearity it suffices to prove $(*)$ for monomials, i.e. for $f(z)=z^k.$ We get
$${1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_0^{2\pi} e^{ik\theta}P_{e^{-i\theta}T}\,d\theta=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left ({1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_0^{2\pi} e^{ik\theta}e^{-in\theta}\,d\theta\, \right )T^n\\ +\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left ({1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_0^{2\pi} e^{ik\theta}e^{in\theta}\,d\theta\right )\, (T^*)^n
=T^k$$
In the last formula we have used the orthonormality properties of the functions $e^{in\theta}.$

**Remark** The formula $(*)$ extends to functions $f(z)$ holomorphic in $|z|<1+\delta.$